# How to present view controller modally while keeping navigation bar present. (For a settings view controller)

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Here is an example of what I'm talking about: https://media.giphy.com/media/3o6nUPLqKrMN64tdNm/giphy.gif Many apps do this. The contacts app when you add a new contact, etc. When I try to present my settings page modally, however, the navigation bar disappears. Any idea how to get around this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a navigation controller with root view controller as your view controller and then present navigation controller.

Comment: Present navigation controller instead. It's just works

Comment: Trivially simple. This is an independent navigation controller, merely so that there can be a place for the done button. It has its own navigation bar — nothing to do with your existing navigation controller and navigation bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a navigation controller with root view controller as your view controller and then present navigation controller. Something like this.

```
let vc =  // your view controller 
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I access the variables in the 2nd view controller from the first view controller?

Comment: @JackGruber Use the segues. Make your Navigation controller as a destination controller. And make your embedded vc as a `topViewController` of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: thanks! One more question, how would I access the 2nd navigation controller from the rootview controller. If I were to do self.navigationController!.viewControllers[0], it would only be using my original navigation controller.

Comment: Nevermind find it in the child ViewControllers array. Thanks!

Comment: Would calling `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` be the correct way to dismiss the vc programmatically then?

Comment: @Eric33187 Yes, using `self.dismiss`  is the correct way.

Comment: Add `nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` if you want a full screen presentation